# Mongo Connector not behaving regularly on Loopback.js tests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jestjs, loopbackjs

I've been trying to figure out why my code behaves unexpectedly

```js
it('Debería detectar cambios en los ultimos chequeos', async () => {
            await givenEmptyDatabase();


            //Generación de mocks
            let taskResult1 = givenTaskResultData();
            let taskResult2 = givenTaskResultData();
            taskResult2.taskName += '2';
            taskResult2.agentResponse.Name += '2';
            await sleep(2000);

            //Inserción de datos
            await taskRepo.create(taskResult1);
            await taskRepo.create(taskResult2);
            await sleep(500);

            let storedTasks = await taskRepo.find({});
            await sleep(500);
            expect(storedTasks .length).toBe(2); //SOMETIMES FAILS???
```

`givenEmptyDatabase()` deletes every document from all collections in mongo.
Here is how it looks:

```js
export async function givenEmptyDatabase() {
    await new HeartbeatRepository(testdb).deleteAll();
    await new TaskResultRepository(testdb).deleteAll();
    await new MailSuscriptionRepository(testdb).deleteAll();
    await new SuscriptionConfirmationRepository(testdb).deleteAll();
}
```

What is weird is that:

*sometimes storedTasks.length == 2, sometimes == 0, sometimes == 4*

**The same thing happens along all my tests:** Simple finds() immediately preceded by simple creates() give different results. I try to make sure I clean the database manualy at the beginning of each test.
Any ideas on why this should be happening?

When I run on debug mode and run over each line step by step, it runs all good .____. (that's the reason why I added those sleep() calls after each DB manipulation statement)

Edit: This is how I'm launching my tests from vscode:

```
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "vscode-jest-tests",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/poller",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/poller/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
            "args": [
                "-i",
                "--runInBand"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/poller/dist/**/*"
            ],
            // "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/poller/.env"
        }
```

Cheers

Comment: How are you running your tests? In parallel?

Comment: Good call. I forgot to mention that I'm running them with --runInBand . I'll add this to the main question.